# How Does Browser recognize Java : windows 7

Tags: windows-7, browser, java

I having trouble Running few sites in my PC, as my browser is not able to recognize the java in my machine. I have below installation of java in my machine

```
jdk1.7.0_71
jre1.6.0_43
jre7
```

in `C:\Program Files\Java`

My Java Home points to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71`

I have below installation of java in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java
jre1.8.0_31
jre6
```

IE from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer`, same behavior with Firefox

When I am accessing PVCS web Site or any site which uses applets I get message stating your java version is out dated and provide me option to either Run site or Update java . If i choose Run the site opens.

IE from `C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer`

When I am accessing PVCS web Site or any site which uses applets I get message stating your java version is out dated and provide me option to either Run site or Update java . If i choose Run I get below message.

Can"t load IA 32-bit .dll on an AMD 64-bit platform.

I want why I am facing this issue. How is Java picked by Browser?

Comment: @Ramhound I have jre6 installed . What If i dont want to intall latest JRE , I am  java developer I want to use JDK1.7 for my development purpose.

Answer (score 1):

In Control Panel, you have Java as an option. There it will tell you all the java versions you have installed on your machine. If Java is not present in your control panel, then the version of Java in your machine was not installed, but placed there. Meaning that you unzipped the java and placed into a folder.

I would recommend you download the latest jre from [www.java.com](http://www.java.com) with the browser you plan on using.

If you want a different version or flavour, then look for the "Not the right operating system? See all Java downloads." link.

- jre = Java Runtime Environment. The minimal requirements to run a java application on your machine.
- jdk = Java Developer Kit. The tool kit to develop java application. Also includes the jre and a lot of other things.

Here are my Java options for my machine if you wish to compare.

Ensure that the folder specified (outline in red) is truly the correct location.
[image]

Ensure that under the Security Tab the check mark for "Enable Java content in the browser"
[image]

In the Advanced Tab, ensure you have selected Default Java for Browsers.
[image]

In Internet Explorer check the following

- Click Tools and then Internet Options
- Select the Security tab, and select the Custom Level button
- Scroll down to Scripting of Java applets
- Make sure the Enable radio button is checked
- Click OK to save your preference

You can also find more information about [here](https://java.com/en/download/help/enable_browser.xml)

Comment: I have installed Java properly , I do see the java 1.7 and 1.6 from c:\program files\java directory in Java Control panel option

Comment: Install the lastest jre version. Ensure you are using the jre 64-bit install for IE 64-bit and jre 32-bit for Firefox.

Comment: thanks for details How do i ensure i am using JRE 64 bit for IE 64 bit adn Jre 32 bit for Firefox . What if i dont want to use latest Jre i want to use JRE 1.7

Comment: You can download the version you want from this website http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/archive-139210.html. Pick Windows x64 = jre-7u80-windows-x64.exe

Answer (score -1):

If you are using firefox on your desktop then you need the 32 bit variant of JRE on your computer. For firefox refer to the article given over [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Java#If_the_Java_plugin_does_not_appear_in_the_Add-ons_Manager_even_though_Java_is_installed) to debug issues related to JAVA 6 or 7. Please note that this applies to Firefox only and not to IE.

You can have multiple versions of JAVA, from multiple vendors running on your computer. But please note that Firefox does tend to flag JAVA as unsafe.

By the way why are you using IE?

Comment: Questions and clarification should be commented on the OP's question rather than your answer. It means you are partly answering the question and unsure about the OP's problem.

Comment: I issued a downvote for asking "By the way why are you using IE?" within an answer.  The user is using IE because they want or are required to use it.  The reason they are using IE isn't important, and certainly the question, shouldn't be part of an answer.  The rest of the answer does not explain how to solve the author's problem.